# Castle Windsor Typed Factory Facility cannot find interface seemingly because of its namespace

Tags: .net-core, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I have a Typed Factory in Castle Windsor registered like

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyTypeFactory>().AsFactory());
```

and the interface registered like

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyType>()
                .ImplementedBy<MyType>().LifestyleTransient()
                .Interceptors(typeof(MyInterceptor));
```

I have also registered the facility like

```
if (!container.Kernel.GetFacilities().Any(f => f is TypedFactoryFacility))
{
  container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>(); // Due to the debugger this line is reached.
}
```

When I try to resolve an instance of IMyClass like

```
var myFactory = container.Resolve<IMyFactory>();
var myClass = myFactory.GetMyClass(myParameter); // This is where I get the exception
```

an exception is thrown with the message

```
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: 'Requested component named 'IMyClass' was not found in the container. Did you forget to register it?
There is one other component supporting requested service 'The.Name.Space.IMyClass'. Is it what you were looking for?'
```

My IMyTypeFactory looks like this:

```
public interface IMyTypeFactory 
{
  IMyType GetIMyType(IMyParameter myParameter);
}
```

MyType constructor looks like this:

```
public MyType(
  IOneProperlyResolvedType oneProperlyResolvedType, 
  IAnotherProperlyResolvedType anotherProperlyResolvedType, 
  IMyParameter myParameter)
        {
            this.oneProperlyResolvedType = oneProperlyResolvedType;
            this.anotherProperlyResolvedType = anotherProperlyResolvedType;
            this.myParameter = myParameter;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see how that can be confusing. It has nothing to do with namespace.

Your factory method is called `GetMyClass` and ['Get' methods lookup components by name](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/35ebd6e5a77de289536b3862f366d6cbfad19ecc/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#get-methods-lookup-components-by-name) so Windsor looks for a component *named* `MyClass`, which happens to be the name of your class sans namespace.

To turn that off change the factory registration to
`.AsFactory(new DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector(getMethodsResolveByName: false)));`

Or rename the method.

Comment: Thank you very much. (My solution was to rename the method to "Create" which is a lot less confusing anyway.)

Comment: In hindsight it is sheer luck that I have used the same naming convention in my Minimum Viable Code than in my production one, otherwise you wouldn't have been able to help. I was confused as h*ll. Thanks again, and have a good day! I think naming mumbo-jumbo is something Windsor Developers should have avoided, but that isn't my business.

Comment: In hindsight, I agree it's not the best default